# Synchronize custom group names across multiple related pivot tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have multiple pivot tables based on a master where I specify custom groups on a field.

The groupings themselves mirror on all the related pivot tables throughout the sheets but the naming I specify does not eg. they use the default naming group 1, group 2, etc as opposed to the name I have specified.

I may have to add/modify groupings on this sheet in the future and I was wondering how I could go about ensuring the names were consistent across all related tables.

What I have tried is creating a slicer on the master table on the custom grouped dimension and linking it to a child table, this did not work, the names remained as their default despite the filter controls working properly for the grouping.